# This discovery was to have a major effect on the treatment of heart disease

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This discovery **was to have** a major effect on the treatment of heart
>   disease.

Does **was to have** mean *supposed* or *destined* in this sentence?

Comment: In practice, the "purpose" sense *(**supposed, intended**)* would be very unlikely with your exact text (apart from anything else, "discoveries" aren't usually "planned", so they're not usually made with a ***goal*** in mind). But you'd have to provide more ***context*** to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, `was to have` doesn't mean 'supposed' or 'destined' in this case, it is merely the standard way of talking about an event in the past without using past tense for the whole sentence.

Comment: Specifically, **the future** of an event in the past!